# How come Stackdriver messes up my error grouping

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-stackdriver

In my experience the Stackdriver Error Reporting service groups unrelated errors together. This is a big problem for me on several levels:

- The titles often do not correlate to the reported errors in "recent samples". So I have to look at the samples for each error to see what errors really happend because the title really can't be trusted.
- I might set an error to "muted" and as a result other errors that are grouped under the same title don't get reported anymore. It might take me months to discover that certain errors have been happening that I wasn't aware of.
- In general I have no overview about what errors are happening in what rate.

This all seems to violate basic functionality for an error reporting system, so I think I must be missing something.

The code is running on Firebase Functions, so the Firebase flavour of Google Cloud Functions and is written in Typescript (compiled to Javascript with Firebase predeploy script).

I log errors using `console.error` with arguments formatted as Error instances like `console.error(new Error('some error message'))`. AFAIK that is the correct way for code running on Node.js.

Is there anything special I can do to make Stackdriver understand my code better?

I have this in a root of my functions deployment:

```
import * as sourceMaps from "source-map-support";
sourceMaps.install();
```

Below is a screenshot of one error category. You see that the error title is "The service is currently unavailable", yet the samples contain errors for "Request contains an invalid argument" and "This request was already locked..."

The error about service and invalid argument could be related to the FCM service, so there is some correlation although I think these are very different errors.

The error about request lock is really something completely unrelated. The word "request" in this context means something really different but the word is the only relationship I can see.

[image: Screenshot of Stackdriver Error Reporting]

Answer (score 0):

The error reporting supports Javascript, but not Typescript as mentioned in the [documentation for the product](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/), nevertheless, you should take a look at your logs and see if they are [properly formatted](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/formatting-error-messages) for them to be ingested in the error reporting.

Also, keep in mind that the errors are grouped based on the guidelines over at [this document](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/grouping-errors), so maybe you won't get the grouping you get due to them.

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: The cloud functions do not run Typescript code. The code is compiled predeploy to Javascript to run on Node.js. I have clarified this in the text now.

I am not using the Stackdriver API. The errors are picked up from `console.error()`and are formatted correctly (as instances of Error objects). I will also mention this.